# Laravel - doesn't work routing

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, routes, http-status-code-404

I have Laravel on my localhost (on Ubuntu if it matters).

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('layouts/tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});
```

I have such route and it work on localhost/public/

But if I try to make new page like localhost/public/test with such route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('layouts/tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});
```

It returns:

```
404 (The requested URL /public/test was not found on this server.)
```

Also, I tried `/test/`, `test` & `/public/test` and none of these worked either.

Comment: Are you using Apache or NGINX? You should first fix your /public Problem.

Comment: do you have `mod-rewrite` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Make another route and simply put in a return statement to check if it works. If you get another 404 your .htaccess file is probably not taking effect.

You need to enable AllowOverride All for your DocumentRoot inside your virtual host.

Something along the lines of:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Just change your AllowOverride to All or add it.